# Runtime error: insertatIndex

Tags: c, arrays, runtime, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int insertAt(int *Arr, int len, int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (num <= Arr[0])
            return 0;
        else if (num >= Arr[len])
            return len + 1;
        else if (num >= Arr[i - 1] && num <= Arr[i])
            return i;
    }
}

int * sortedArrayInsertNumber(int *Arr, int len, int num){
    int *output = (int *)malloc((len + 1)*sizeof(int));

    if (len <= 0)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= len+1; ++i, ++j) {
        if (i == insertAt(Arr, len, num) && j==i) {
            output[j] = num;
            --i;
        }
        else if(insertAt(Arr,len,num)==len+1) {
            output[j] = num;
        }
        else {
            output[j] = Arr[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    int input[5] = {2,4,6,8,10};
    int *out = (int*)malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    out = sortedArrayInsertNumber(input, 5, 12);
    for(int i=0;i<6;++i) {
        printf("%d\n", out[i]);
    }
}
```

When I try out this test case, it gives me a runtime error sometimes. Other times, it outputs:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
```

Which makes no sense?

Also, is there a way to make my code better?

The question requires me to insert a value `num` at its appropriate index.

Comment: You are leaking memory allocating out and after overwrite its value with the one returned by `sortedArrayInsertNumber`

Comment: `Arr[len]` will access the array out of bounds `Arr[5]`. Indices start form `0` up to `4` in your case.

Comment: @LPs Even when I was simply using 
`int *out; 
out = sortedArrayInputNumber(Arr, 5, 12); `
the same problem persists (note:  it gives me runtime error only sometimes, while other times it gives me the right answer as mentioned above). I am returning a completely new array "output" in sortedArrayInsertNumber function which has length len+1.

Comment: You have a good answer to look at, now.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `insertAt` there is at least two attempts to access memory beyond the array. The first one is in the statement

```
else if (num >= Arr[len])
                    ^^^^
```

And the second one is in the statement

```
else if (num >= Arr[i - 1] && num <= Arr[i])
                    ^^^^^^
```

when the variable `i` is equal to 0.

The function `sortedArrayInsertNumber` starts with a potential memory leak when the variable len is equal at least 0 because at first a memory is allocated and then there is exit from the function with A NULL pointer.

```
int * sortedArrayInsertNumber(int *Arr, int len, int num){
    int *output = (int *)malloc((len + 1)*sizeof(int));

    if (len <= 0)
        return NULL;
    // ...
```

Also it is a bad idea when the length of an array has type `int` instead of type `size_t`.

To call several times the function `insertAt` in the function `sortedArrayInsertNumber` does not make sense and breaks the loop.

In the main there is again a memory leak

```
int *out = (int*)malloc(6*sizeof(int));
out = sortedArrayInsertNumber(input, 5, 12);
```

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

size_t insertAt( const int *a, size_t n, int num ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( num < a[i] ) ) i++;

    return i;
}

int * sortedArrayInsertNumber( const int *a, size_t n, int num )
{
    int *b = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( b )
    {
        size_t pos = insertAt( a, n, num );

        size_t i = 0;
        for ( ; i < pos; i++ ) b[i] = a[i];

        b[i] = num;

        for ( ; i < n; i++ ) b[i+1] = a[i];
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int input[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( input ) / sizeof( *input );

    int *out = sortedArrayInsertNumber( input, N, 12 );

    if ( out )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N + 1; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", out[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( out );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 4 6 8 10 12
```

Instead of the loops in the function `sortedArrayInsertNumber` you can use standard C function `memcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. 

However, I am only accessing one illegal memory (the first one pointed out by you). In case of the second one, in case, num <= Arr[0], the program would return 0 before it reaches the third conditional in the for loop, isn't it? 

Should I be declaring the output array after I've checked if `len <= 0` to avoid potential memory leaks?

Comment: Also, would it make much of a difference if I had just used 

`int* out; 
out = sortedArrayInsertNumber(input, 5, 12); 
`

Also, is there anything else I can do to improve my code? What if I was only allowed to use one for loop for the solution?

Comment: @ritika_13 I was showed in my answer how the functions can be defined. Investigate them.

Comment: Very well. Can you just answer:

Should I be declaring the output array after I've checked if `len <= 0` to avoid potential memory leaks?

Comment: @ritika_13 The both your functions are wrong and have undefined behavior. So it is not clear what you want. I showed how the functions can be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've understood the trouble with my code.